# Error while trying to use existing sqlitedabase in android studio

Tags: android, sqlite

I tried to use a existing sqlite database in my application and and put my database file (that I created by Db browser for sqlite portable software in windows 7 OS)in assets folder of android studio, I write a databaseOpenHelper class like this :

```
package com.example.javad.dbproject;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
public class myDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static String DBPATH = "C:/Users/Payam/AndroidStudioProjects/dbProject/app/src/main/assets/";
private static String DBNAME = "database1";
private SQLiteDatabase myDatabase;
private final Context myContext;
//constructor
public myDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DBNAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
}
//create an empty db, and replace with our chosen db
public void createDatabase() throws IOException{
    if (!checkDatabase()) {
        this.getWritableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDatabase();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database from system assets");
        }
    }
}
//Check if our database already exists
private boolean checkDatabase(){
    SQLiteDatabase checkableDatabase = null;
    try {
        checkableDatabase =
                SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DBPATH+DBNAME, null,
                        SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }
    catch (SQLiteException e) {
        //our database doesn't exist, so we'll return false below.
    }
    if (checkableDatabase != null) {
        checkableDatabase.close();
    }
    return checkableDatabase != null ? true : false;
}
//Copy our database from the Application's assets
//over the empty DB for use
private void copyDatabase() throws IOException {
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DBNAME);
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(DBPATH+DBNAME);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}
public void openDatabase() throws SQLException {
    myDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DBPATH+DBNAME, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}
@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if(myDatabase != null)
        myDatabase.close();
    super.close();
}
    @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
//Handle creation tasks, etc.
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
//Handle upgrade tasks, etc.
}
}
```

To use an Instance of above Helper class,I use this piece of code in main activity java class, inside of onCreat method:

```
myDatabaseHelper mySeinfeldDBHelper = new myDatabaseHelper();
mySeinfeldDBHelper = new myDatabaseHelper(this);
try {
mySeinfeldDBHelper.createDatabase();
}
catch (IOException e) {
throw new Error("Failed to create Seinfeld database");
}
try {
mySeinfeldDBHelper.openDatabase();
}
catch(SQLException e) {
throw e;
}
```

But after running app application crashes and within logcat debugger this message appears and :

```
"Failed to open database'C:/Users/Payam/AndroidStudioProjects/dbProject/app/src/main/assets/database1'.
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database"

"FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.Error: Error copying database from system assets"
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: You've specified that the database is on a path relative to `C:\` drive. This is not accessible on an Android system. You need to specify it relative to your assets folder.

Comment: Yes, you need to put database on your device.

Answer (score 0):

Your DBPATH/DBNAME should look something like this

```
 context.getAssets().open("sqlite_filename_here..");//This will return a InputStream
```